# No partition on installation type when installing Ubuntu 18.04 with multi-boot on windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, uefi

I used to use Multi-boot option with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04

But I need to change my size of HDD for Ubuntu and I want to use 18.04

So, I did it as follows

1. Delete GRUB multi-booting option
2. Delete partition for Ubuntu
3. Re-install Windows10 by recovery system
4. Make a partition (See fig.1)
5. Try to install Ubuntu 18.04
6. Can't see my partitioned area on 'Installation type' (See Fig.2)

What did I miss for this problem?

Please Help me some :D

Thanks

[Setting for windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmtaE.png)

[Ubuntu Installation type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74bp0.jpg)

Comment: Is system UEFI or BIOS. Your Windows partitions looks more like a BIOS/MBR configuration. Microsoft has required vendors to install in UEFI/gpt mode since Windows 8 released in 2012, so hardware since then is UEFI. BIOS/MBR option is available primarily as some large vendors wanted compatibility with older Windows 7 system hardware. But however you install Windows, you need to install Ubuntu in same boot mode. Both UEFI or both BIOS. And how you boot install media UEFI or BIOS is then how it installs for both systems.

Comment: Thanks for the Comment. Yes. the system is UEFI. (It can be selected on BIOS setting menu. CSM OS or UEFI OS. and I select UEFI)

Comment: Have you updated UEFI and if SSD, its firmware? And have you turned off Windows fast start up which sets hibernation flag. Then Linux NTFS driver cannot correctly see the NTFS partitions. Shows installer with screen shots. Both BIOS purple accessibility screen & UEFI black grub menu screen
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI
Also shows Windows 10 screens or similar to Windows 8
https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi

Answer (score 0):

1.It seems like your partition prepared for ubuntu isn't *formatted*.But it's not needed.
2.Did you select"something else" on setup?[Like This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8ajz.png)
3.If you do things right,you should see something like this[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdOeH.png)

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Sure. I select "Something else". It is my 2nd time to install Ubuntu. I used it with multi-booting both Windows10 and Ubuntu 16.04 for 6 months. Then I want to use Ubuntu 18.04 with larger hdd storage. So I delete the partition and separate partition again with big size. Then this thing happens. Don't know why I can see any separate storage spaces.

Comment: maybe yooru'd check your BIOS(or UEFI,whatever)for "secure boot"and "disk protection"(or something like this).Some wired bug may occur if you enable them.